# VBA Excel Compile error: Expected: end of statement caused (When Call .vbs from Python or direct execution

Tags: python, excel, vba

I am trying to Create VB Script for Report updating

If I am running through excel sheet not facing any issue, but while running through python always getting Compile error: Expected: end of statement

Below is the Script:

```vb
Sub PivotTable()

Dim PTable As PivotTable
Dim PCache As PivotCache
Dim PRange As Range
Dim PSheet As Worksheet
Dim DSheet As Worksheet
Dim LR As Long
Dim LC As Long

On Error Resume Next

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Worksheets("Pivot Sheet").Delete 'This will delete the exisiting pivot table worksheet
Worksheets.Add After:=ActiveSheet ' This will add new worksheet
ActiveSheet.Name = "Pivot Sheet" ' This will rename the worksheet as "Pivot Sheet"
On Error GoTo 0

Set PSheet = Worksheets("Pivot Sheet")
Set DSheet = Worksheets("TestResultDetails")

'Find Last used row and column in data sheet
LR = DSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
LC = DSheet.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

'Set the pivot table data range
Set PRange = DSheet.Cells(1, 1).Resize(LR, LC)

'Set pivot cahe
Set PCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(xlDatabase, SourceData:=PRange)

'Create blank pivot table
Set PTable = PCache.CreatePivotTable(TableDestination:=PSheet.Cells(1, 1), TableName:="Report")


'Insert country to Row Filed
With PSheet.PivotTables("Report").PivotFields("Modules")
.Orientation = xlRowField
End With

'Insert country to Row Filed
With PSheet.PivotTables("Report").PivotFields("ExecutionStatus")
.Orientation = xlColumnField
End With

'Insert country to Row Filed
With PSheet.PivotTables("Report").PivotFields("ExecutionStatus")
.Orientation = xlDataField
End With

'Format Pivot Table
PSheet.PivotTables("Report").ShowTableStyleRowStripes = True
PSheet.PivotTables("Report").TableStyle2 = "PivotStyleMedium14"

'Show in Tabular form
PSheet.PivotTables("Report").RowAxisLayout xlTabularRow


Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Please help me to identify the issue

Comment: Please format the code - select it and type `ctrl-k`.
.. [Formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)... [Formatting sandbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox)

Comment: Often, in Python code, *`...end of statement`* means there is a missing quote or maybe one too many quotes.

Comment: Did you search with the error message -`Expected: end of statement` - got some hits.